# How to use "for" and change values in a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, for-loop

if have the hash:

```
hash = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

tried this:

```
for value in hash.values do
    value = value * value
end
```

but return the same value no the value desired, I find a solution:

```
hash.transform_values{ |value| value * value}
=> {:a=>1, :b=>4, :c=>9}
```

but want to do with a for loop, how to do?

Comment: Why do you want to use a for loop? For loops are exceedingly rare in Ruby.

Comment: "exceedingly rare" - I'd even go as far to say I've never seen one except in Ruby beginner questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the closest to what you want

```
for k, v in hash do
  hash[k] = v * v
end
```

Answer (score 3):

We have a rich standard lib to work with collections in Ruby. It is very useful and covers most needed cases. We have a great methods [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [Enumerable#filter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter), [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) in ruby and many others. Please, read the documentation.

The general purpose way is to generate a new hash:

```rb
new_hash = hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), acc| acc[k] = v * v }
```

For Ruby since 2.4.0 you can use the `Hash#transform_values` method:

```rb
hash.transform_values{ |value| value * value }
```

We prefer to use `map, filter, transform_values` instead of `for` because of several reasons. Such as:

- minimize data mutation and side effects;
- ability to chain methods like `collection.filter(&:empty?).map(&:size)`

Comment: Nope, `Hash#transform_values` is the best here. Straight to the point, no extra crust.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Data mutation is a bad habit. This approach may cause side effects.

Comment: What data mutation? Looks like someone doesn't practice what he preaches :)

Comment: Ah, sorry i think you talk about first answer. `transform_values` is ok, but the `Hash#transform_values` is a method from the Rails-specific `ActiveSupport` lib.

Comment: Nope, it's in core since 2.4.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem now is that the OP _knew_ about transform_values from the start and they deemed it unsatistactory. Could you add a few words as to why it should be preferable to a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.each{ |k, v| hash[k] = v * v }
```